# Dual CPU memory allocation performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, memory-management, cpu

I have a problem with a multithreaded code when I use it on a specific server with 2 CPU. The server is running on Windows 7 x64 with a Bi-Xeon E5-2697Wv2 12 Cores 2,7 GHz; 64 Gb RAM (8X8 Gb 1866 MHz); motherboard SuperMicro X9DAI. My executable is generated using Visual Studio MSVC 2013 and multithreaded using OpenMP.

Now the problem is that I have better performance using 1 thread versus 24 threads... This problem is only visible on this computer and when I attached a profiler (CodeXL) I get the following result :

- 1 thread : ~3% of the execution time is inside malloc/free(~3/~2)
- 24 threads : ~64% of the execution time is inside malloc/free(~33%/~31%)

The code is complex and I can't post an example, but basically it is a monte carlo code, there is a little number of dynamic allocations (an initialization phase creates all needed data), it remains just one dynamic allocation at the begin of one event to store event data. The code doesn't contain any mutex, each thread work without any communication except at the begin and the end of calculation.

My knowledge in server and Dual CPU architecture is very limited and I want to know if there is something I can do to avoid this problem (BIOS Option ?), my guess is there is a controller that choose which CPU RAM will be used and it this operation make a slow down...

Thank you for reading.

**EDIT :** 
I wrote a little benchmark to evaluate the performance decrease of malloc/free, here is the code :

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <afx.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// malloc allocation size tab
int allocSize[] =
{
    4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072
};

int main()
{
    // number max of thread
    int nbThreadMax = omp_get_max_threads();
    // malloc/free iteration per bench
    unsigned int nbIteration = 1000000;

    // Empty res tab
    std::vector<double> emptyRes(16, 0.);
    // Duration per thread
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> avgDuration(nbThreadMax, emptyRes);

    int nbThread = 1;
    unsigned int idxt = 0;
    while (nbThread <= nbThreadMax)
    {
        // Current bench result
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> threadResult(nbThread, emptyRes);

        std::cout << "Thread : " << nbThread << std::endl;

        // Create parrallel region
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(nbThread)
        {
            int nt = omp_get_thread_num();

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            {
                int allocationSize = allocSize[i];

                std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
                start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < nbIteration; ++j)
                {
                    void* pData = malloc(allocationSize);
                    free(pData);
                }
                end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

                threadResult[nt][i] += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() / 1000.;
            }
        }

        // Sum
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j <= idxt; ++j)
            {
                avgDuration[idxt][i] += threadResult[j][i];
            }
            // /!\  Normalize for one thread /!\
            avgDuration[idxt][i] /= nbThread;
        }

        ++idxt;
        // Increase thread number (X2)
        if (nbThread >= nbThreadMax)
            break;
        if (nbThread * 2 > nbThreadMax)
            nbThread = nbThreadMax;
        else
            nbThread = nbThread * 2;
    }

    // Write results
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("resultats.csv");
        ofs << "NbThread;";
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {
            ofs << allocSize[i] << ";";
        }
        ofs << std::endl;

        int nbThread = 1;
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n < idxt; ++n)
        {
            ofs << nbThread << ";";
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
            {
                ofs << avgDuration[n][i] << ";";
            }
            ofs << std::endl;
            nbThread = nbThread * 2;
        }

        ofs.close();
    }
}
```

Here are the result optained on my server :
[malloc/free duration /thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nDYf.png)
[malloc/free performance factor /thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzoRU.png)

Is this kind of result showing an issue or is it a normal performance decrease ?

Comment: 24 threads on 2 CPU's?

Comment: Threads are no the holy grail of performance. Especially on NUMA machines

Comment: yes 24 threads on 2 CPU's, I haven't precise that I have 8X8Gb for the RAM.
So you mean that I can't do anything ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since each CPU has 12 cores it's quite reasonable

Comment: @user3513887 I have overlooked that each has 12 Cores.

Comment: It seems like it's quite possibly that something is horribly wrong with the hardware or software on this machine. It may be worth running memory benchmarks or multithreaded computing benchmarks. Maybe the debug heap is enabled.

Comment: Did you try replacing malloc/free? (I don't know how hard that is on windows, I only know that it is trivial on linux and there are many implementations to try)

Comment: @David Schwartz : Do you know a good memory benchmark running on windows ?

Comment: @MarcGlisse: malloc/free implementation used is MSVC12 implementation, I am going to check if I can use an other implementation easilly and if it solves my performance issues

Comment: If Your algorithm has 3% serial part and 97% parallel part and You speed up the parallel part 48x, now the serial part would be cca 60% of the time. I see nothing wrong on those numbers.

Comment: I have edited my message to show the performance decrease versus the number of threads, I try to put a new malloc implementation but on windows it is not so simple...

Comment: @user3513887: To be honest, that's because you're using C. C++ explicitly allows you to override `operator new`.

Answer (score 2):

BIOS options are far, far too exotic. The easiest solution is to slightly stray away from the Standard C method and use a native Windows method.

The first test would be to replace `malloc/free` with a `HeapAlloc`. The benefit here is that `HeapAlloc` can support multiple heaps, and with `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` each of those heaps can be single-threaded. This does *not* mean you must call `HeapFree` on the same thread. You can call `HeapAlloc` on the worker thread, store the result in the allocated memory block, join with the main thread (memory barrier here), then on the main thread collect all the data from worker threads and call `HeapFree` from the main thread. Since the worker threads no longer exist, there's no serialization risk.

The second improvement (if necessary) would be to check NUMA support. It would be best to pin threads to a CPU and allocate memory from the 4xGB connected to that particular CPU. But this is far more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

One way in Standard C11/C++11 would be to create a one-entry cache *per thread*. In `mymalloc`, check if the single cache entry can satisfy the request (no locking needed). If not, defer to regular `malloc`.

Most of the intelligence is in `myfree`. If there's already a cache entry, you need to decide what to do: keep the oldest, keep the newest, keep smallest, keep biggest, or potentially some other strategy. (If you need the size here, `mymalloc` must over-allocate by `sizeof(size_t)` and prefix the requested size).